# Wingpanel icon menu items no effect upon clicking

Tags: wingpanel

For some reason clicking of the wingpanel icon's menu items has only once worked for a small amount of time.

They seemed to work for a few minutes so I presumed the problem had been resolved, without me realising it. A while later I tried to click one of the menu items and there was no effect again.

Anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Does this happen all the time or is this only happening as of your last boot?

Comment: no, it happens all the time

Comment: Are you opening the indicator menu with a left click or right click? There's a known issue where opening an indicator with right click won't let you click on anything afterwords https://bugs.launchpad.net/wingpanel/+bug/1448450

Comment: Ah, thank you! I must've right clicked the time it worked haha.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since it seems OP has verified that it is related to a known bug and there's not really any question to be answered/action to be taken.

Answer (score 2):

You can try running the following command in terminal,my wingpanel was acting weird too.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall wingpanel
```

You can instead try these commands too, the purge command completely deletes the wingpanel alongwith all its configuration files. So I think you might first want to try the above reinstall command, it worked for me.

```
sudo apt-get purge wingpanel
sudo apt-get install wingpanel
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem, and I *think* it was a conflict between my usb mouse and my touchpad. I would be using my usb mouse, and all of the sudden your problem would happen to me. I disabled my touchpad in settings (since it doesn't work that well anyway since I spilled coffee on it) and I haven't had the problem since.